# Mocha PhantomJS setup

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js

I wonder if there is a better way to test mocha test with phantomJS then having a html file for every test. So is there a grunt plugin or such a thing that let me write my test in single JavaScript files and concatenate the files when running the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen `grunt-mocha`? Also, why do you have to have an HTML file for every test? You can include multiple suites in the same HTML file.

```
<script src="spec1.js"></script>
<script src="spec2.js"></script>
<script src="spec3.js"></script>
<script>
  mocha.run();
</script>
```